# Is there a way to return a total count and rows in a single psql query?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    id                  BIGSERIAL,
    favorite_color      TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO person (favorite_color) VALUES ('red');
INSERT INTO person (favorite_color) VALUES ('green');
INSERT INTO person (favorite_color) VALUES ('blue');
INSERT INTO person (favorite_color) VALUES ('blue');
INSERT INTO person (favorite_color) VALUES ('blue');
```

I want to now query the table to give me a `COUNT` for all the rows where `favorite_color = blue` AND return all the rows. How can I achieve the following output with a single postgresql query?

```
{
    "total" 3,
    "results": [
        {"id": 3, "favorite_color": "blue"},
        {"id": 4, "favorite_color": "blue"},
        {"id": 5, "favorite_color": "blue"},
    ]
}
```

I know how to write SQL statements, I am asking if it is possible to write a single SQL statement to achieve my desired result, oppose to hitting the database twice (once for the count, second for results).

Comment: So in stead of "oppose to hitting the database twice" you are only hitting it once, but harder ? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative with a scalar subquery and no window function or `min()`. Leave the optimizer alone to do its job.

```sql
with p as (select * from person where favorite_color = 'blue')
select jsonb_build_object(
 'total', count(*), 
 'results',  
 (
  select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) 
    from (select id, favorite_color from p) t
 ))
from p;
```

Comment: The seems to be returning the count of all the rows in the table, not the rows that match the query.

Comment: @KeSi-Kung Oh, of course. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the windowed version of `count()` to get the count.

```
SELECT json_build_object('total', max(total),
                         'results', json_agg(element))
       FROM (SELECT count(*) OVER () AS total,
                    row_to_json(person) AS element
                    FROM person
                    WHERE favorite_color = 'blue') AS x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d14680c342599443653c43e07d8e6218)

Comment: Why is the use of `max()` needed here?

Comment: @KeSi-Kung: Because of the aggregation `json_agg()` implies. Since `total` is the same for every row, one could also use `min()` or possibly other aggregation functions.